# Rails is showing me this message every time that I do a request, I tried putting 2 png images in the root directory but It didn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apple-touch-icon

```
Started GET "/apple-touch-icon.png" for ::1 at 2015-02-08 16:46:28 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/apple-touch-icon.png"):
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /Users/Raphel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/Raphel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/Raphel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/Raphel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/Raphel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/Raphel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/Raphel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/Raphel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/Raphel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (83.4ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the code used to include the icons in your application?

Comment: I thought I just had to put the files in that directory. Sorry, It's my first time whit Rails. How do I include  the icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the images in your `app/assets/images` directory and restart your server.

**Update**

Here's how you can include an apple-touch icon...

**app/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <%= favicon_link_tag "apple-touch-icon-100.png",
                         rel: "apple-touch-icon",
                         sizes: "100x100",
                         type: "image/png" %>
</head>
```

Ensure `apple-touch-icon-100.png` exists within the `app/assets/images` directory.

Comment: I just tried that, but It did't work. I am using 2 images of 100x100

Comment: do you have an image named `apple-touch-icon.png` in your `app/assets/images` folder?

Comment: Yes, I put it there as You suggested

Comment: This did not work for me, as my app is getting requests for "apple-touch-icon-152x152.png", and "apple-touch-icon-120x120.png".  I tried those in the sizes field, but still get an ActionController::RoutingError